# How to decrease a list according to another list?

Tags: c#, list

The scenario is this:

I am writing a windows service for my website. The mission of it is to do this every day:

It should get a list of saved images from database and set it to list `A`. And also get a list of files uploaded to the server and set it to list `B`.

I know that A.Count() is always <= than b.Count().

It should delete those uploaded files that exist in list `B` but not exist in list `A`.

Now I have two questions:

1. Imagine that my domain is `domain.com`; How to get the `Images` folder in it from the windows service?
2. How to distinct list `B` according to list `A` to find that which images should be delete?

Comment: Does your list B also stores in database? Do you want to get result list of files, which were not uploaded to the server? Does your service works on the same machine as website?

Comment: Yes.It works on the same machine. There may be some images that have been uploaded but have not been saved in the database(because of some reasons). I want to find them and delete them every day.

Comment: @Carlos Landeras :Wow thanks, you solved a big problem with my question.:-|

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141747/i-say-thank-you-and-it-gets-edited-out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With linq, this should be as below:

```
var toDeleteList=listB.Except(listB.Intersect(listA));
```

**Update:**

Just dicovered a more precise way:

```
var toDeleteList=listB.Except(listA);
```

Comment: Actually, as it is two separate questions (same context for you, but really, this is two problems, with two possible answer), you should create another question and remove this one from your post. This will be easier to manager, because there's no "partially solved" status.

Answer (score 1):

Create your comparer class. It would contain the params of the files, you want to compare (name and size in my case). Then upload data with your uploaded files to some datatable and linq it to file list. Load the files from your filesystem to another list. And use Victor Mukherjee aproach to find result list.

Your File class:

```
class UniqeFile
{
   public string FileName;
   public long Length;
}
```

Your code:

```
DataTable yourDataTable;
DateTime yourBeginDateTime, yourEndDateTime;

var listA = new DirectoryInfo("yourPath").GetFiles().Where(fl => fl.CreationTime >= yourBeginDateTime && fl.CreationTime >= yourEndDateTime).Select(fl => new UniqeFile() { FileName = fl.Name, Length = fl.Length }).ToList();

var listB = yourDataTable.Select().Select(dr => new UniqeFile() { FileName = dr["fileName"].ToString(), Length = long.Parse(dr["fileSize"].ToString()) }).ToList();

var ListC = listB.Except(listB.Intersect(listA));
```

Comment: Well,do you think the path would be : "C:\HostingSpaces\domain.com\wwwroot\Images"?

I say this because when I dont have write access to the server I see an error that says you dont have access to the path "C:\HostingSpaces\domain.com\wwwroot\Images".

Do I think right?

Comment: Well, your service account should have the permissions to read data from your hosting directory. It is hard to say if your are right without seen the path myself. But suppose you are right